# Java Network Data Exchange Architecture

Tags: java, networking

I'm currently redesigning a old application of mine. I'm unsure in which form to transfer the data from clients to servers and between different servers. Previously there was only one server that was handling the clients. The exchange of data was done by serialization and a custom "IO-Solution" (I didn't use a framework like netty before. I do intend to use netty now tho.)

My question now is should I even use serialization? I have various types of servers (login, "cluster manager" (tracks other servers status etc and assigns tasks to them), servers that handle clients and provide access to the cluster, and as I probably will call them "object or instance servers". Those last servers run specific scenarios like a "battle" or a specific world / part of the map.

An alternative to serialization would be to use a custom byte based protocol and parse it step by step from a buffer...

If you need more information for a good answere please ask.

Comment: How about using json to pass your messages? it can be easily converted to objects and vice-versa.

Comment: This is Java not JavaScript... Don't really see how I build a Object from JSON without having the same Class on both sides again.

Comment: @Nightmares: JSON originated with Javascript, but can nowadays be considered a standardized cross-platform message format, with parsers available for all mainstream langauges, including at least 3 for Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution depends on the details of your scenario and plans for its future. If:

1. Your various servers and clients all written in Java
2. You control their development
3. You control their deployment so that the versions can be kept in synch
4. Network communication is not performance critical
5. Factors 1-4 will remain that way in the foreseeable future

then Java serialization is the best solution and I would not hesitate to use it.

- If factor 1 is in doubt, you definitely want a standardized cross-platform solution like JSON, XML, [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/protocolbuffers/), [Apache Thrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift) or [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One).
- If factor 2 is in doubt, you want a *popular* standardized cross-platform solution, which narrows the field a bit, with XML and JSON at the top.
- If factor 3 is in doubt, you want a protocol that can be extended and versioned in a controlled manner. Java serialization can do that to some degree, but I doubt it's the best solution. I don't have much experience though; you'll have to see what solution supports this best.
- If factor 4 is in doubt, a custom byte based protocol may be the best solution, but I'd also research / run some tests on the other options to see how they perform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me decide. Network performance is performance critical which means I'm left with only one choice: a custom byte based protocol or similar. XML parsing or similar data structures add at least 2 layers of work to the entire thing: parsing the structure and then parsing the nodes values. When using a byte based protocol I can just reassemble the primitive types without performance loss (or at least almost none).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo). It's serialization, only much faster. You could also try Google protocol buffers.

Comment: Looks promising but what I consider a problem with Serialization is that I do have to place all classes on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarks of different serialization libraries:
https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/